# Use the value of getMonth() in an if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple calendar and I was wondering if it was possible to use the value of the getMonth() function in an if statement to check which months to hide and which month to display.

Javascript:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();

if n = 0 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";
}
if n = 1 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";
}
if n = 2 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";
}
if n = 3 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";
}
if n = 4 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";
}
if n = 5 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";
}
if n = 6 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";
}
if n = 7 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";
}
if n = 8 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";
}
if n = 9 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";
}
if n = 10 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";
}
if n = 11 {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "block";
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="January">January</div>
    <div id="February">February</div>
    <div id="March">March</div>
    <div id="April">April</div>
    <div id="May">May</div>
    <div id="June">June</div>
    <div id="July">July</div>
    <div id="August">August</div>
    <div id="September">September</div>
    <div id="October">October</div>
    <div id="November">November</div>
    <div id="December">December</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the goal just to display the month name in the container div?

Comment: oh boy... make an array an index into it instead of repeating code like that

Comment: You might be over killing it with all the code. Couldn't you simply go to the .container and hide all it's children and then show only the month you want?

Comment: This is a pretty large and innecesary code (not judging). Someone answered your question but this could be reduced (a lot).

Comment: you need to rewrite your JS, use loop `.container > div`  instead define it one by one

Comment: Sorry about the mess. I tend to do that during testing.

Comment: agree with ewwink, you absolutely need a loop right now. I'm going to post an example for you. Won't try it, maybe I'll make a mistake, but you need to understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible, you need to use correct syntax `if(...)` and use comparison operator `===` rather than assignment `=`, you can shorten the code a lot, something like this:

```
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "none";


if (n === 0) {
    document.getElementById("January").style.display = "block";
}
if (n === 1) {
    document.getElementById("February").style.display = "block";
}
if (n === 2) {
    document.getElementById("March").style.display = "block";
}
if (n === 3) {
    document.getElementById("April").style.display = "block";
}
if (n === 4) {
    document.getElementById("May").style.display = "block";
}
if (n === 5) {
    document.getElementById("June").style.display = "block";
}
if (n === 6) {
    document.getElementById("July").style.display = "block";
}
if (n === 7) {
    document.getElementById("August").style.display = "block";
}
if (n === 8) {
    document.getElementById("September").style.display = "block";
}
if (n === 9) {
    document.getElementById("October").style.display = "block";
}
if (n === 10) {
    document.getElementById("November").style.display = "block";
}
if (n === 11) {
    document.getElementById("December").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a lot of uneccessary code to display the current month

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" });
document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = '<div class="'+n+'">'+n+'</div>'
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

[`Date.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) is supported in all major browsers now, and returns the month name *(`long` for full name)* in the language you specify, from any valid date object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite your code. I'm going to give you a little example because I'm nice today ;)

```
var i = -1;
var d = new Date();
var months = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

while (months[++i]) { // basically means : while there is something in months. months[0] = "January", months[1] = "Febuary"..., months[11] = "December"
 if (d.getMonth() == i) //i = 0, 1, 2, 3..., 11. Used to detect current month
  document.getElementById(months[i]).style.display = "block"; // Display the month
 else
  document.getElementById(months[i]).style.display = "none"; // hide the month
}
```

Voila. Didn't try but I'm pretty sure it works.
This while is pretty simple, but when you're making heavier operation, you should use [web workers](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp) in order to not block your UI while you're building your calendar (I guess that's what you're coding).

PS : Sorry for people downvoting you. I'll upvote you because I think your question could help beginner level developers. Sometimes crual developers forget that they were noobs too at the beginning. Good luck in your learning ;)

EDIT : Here is a snippet.

```js
var i = -1;
var d = new Date();
var months = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

// Hide / Show the current month
while (months[++i]) { // basically means : while there is something in months. months[0] = "January", months[1] = "Febuary"..., months[11] = "December"
 if (d.getMonth() == i) //i = 0, 1, 2, 3..., 11. Used to detect current month
  document.getElementById(months[i]).style.display = "block"; // Display the month
 else
  document.getElementById(months[i]).style.display = "none"; // hide the month
}
```

```css
.month {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:#F0F0F0;
  
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="January" class="month">
  January
</div>
<div id="Febuary" class="month">
  Febuary
</div>
<div id="March" class="month">
  March
</div>
<div id="April" class="month">
  April
</div>
<div id="May" class="month">
  May
</div>
<div id="June" class="month">
  June
</div>
<div id="July" class="month">
  July
</div>
<div id="August" class="month">
  August
</div>
<div id="September" class="month">
  September
</div>
<div id="October" class="month">
  October
</div>
<div id="November" class="month">
  November
</div>
<div id="December" class="month">
  December
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use the month name at all. The month can be in DOM order with a class of "calendarMonth" that by default is hidden. You can then just apply a style to show the one you want, and remove it when it needs to be hidden.

The following generates some DOM elements first, then *showMonth* uses a simple method based on the month number to work out which month to show. It's independent of the actual month name, using the default language of the host to set the month names.

You may need to provide a default set of month names in case options for *toLocaleString* aren't supported.

```js
// Add funciton to show selected month
(function() {
  // Date to generate month names in host default language
  var d = new Date(2017,0,1);
  var monthNames = new Array(12).fill('');
  monthNames.forEach(function(x, i, arr) {
    d.setMonth(i);
    arr[i] = d.toLocaleString(undefined, {month:'long'});
  })
  var body = document.body;
  // Keep array of month divs
  var monthDivs = [];
 
  // Add a select to select a month. Mimics getMonth
  // Add divs for months
  var sel = body.appendChild(document.createElement('select'));
  monthNames.forEach(function(month, i){
    sel.appendChild(new Option(month, month));
    var div = body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    div.className = 'calendarMonth';
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(month));
    if (i == 0) div.className += ' visible';
    monthDivs.push(div);
  });
 
  sel.addEventListener('change', showMonth, false);

  // Hide all shown months and show selected month
  function showMonth() {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.visible'), function (div) {
      div.classList.remove('visible');
    });
    // This could be date.getMonth() of some date object
    var monthNum = this.selectedIndex;
    if (monthNum > -1) {
      monthDivs[monthNum].classList.add('visible');
    };
  }
}());
```

```css
.calendarMonth {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.visible {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its much better to use `switch-case` instead of `if-else`
In your code all the `if` are begin checked to see if the condition is matched.

Using switch-case it much more efficeinet code.

```
switch( n ){
   case 0:
   ... 
   break;
case 1:
   ... 
   break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this would be a more elegant solution while still using vanilla Javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="month-container">
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var months = new Object();
  months[0] = "January";
  months[1] = "February";
  months[2] = "March";
  months[3] = "April";
  months[4] = "May";
  months[5] = "June";
  months[6] = "July";
  months[7] = "August";
  months[8] = "September";
  months[9] = "October";
  months[10] = "November";
  months[11] = "December";

  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.getMonth();

  container = document.getElementById("month-container");
  container.innerHTML = months[n];
</script>
</html>
```